# Close modal window containing ASP MVC Ajax form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, modal-dialog

in a webapp I'm using an ASP MVC Ajax form in a modal window. I do not use any specific jQuery code, only some to open the modal window (i.e. showModal() function):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Open", "Add", "Home", new {id = Model.Id}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "modal", OnSuccess = "showModal()"})
```

This code loads my form (partial view) into a div and opens it as a modal window. In the form submit ActionResult I just use the default ModelState object to validate it, and in case of an error I return the same partial view containing model errors. This works fine except for the following situation: when the model contains no errors I want to auto-close the modal window. I tried the following:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Home", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "modal", OnSuccess = "hideModal(); alert('Saved');"}))
```

However, when the model contains errors the Ajax call is still valid, so OnSuccess will be called. I tried to solve this by sending an error HttpStatusCode in the partial view, but then the div is not updated with the new html.
I think the only solution is sending a partial view containing javascript code that closes the modal window when the model contains no errors, but this solution is not very neat in my opinion. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had to do the same thing today. The solution I came up with was to return a JsonResult with a property set to true when the action succeeded. In the OnSuccess callback of the AjaxOptions I checked for the property and closed my modal window.

Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hold(JobStatusNoteViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do work
        return Json(new {success = true});
    }

    return PartialView("JobStatusNote", model);
 }
```

PartialView

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "JobStatusForm", OnSuccess = "closePopUp" })) { %>
<div id="JobStatusForm">
    <!-- Form -->
</div>
<% } %>  

<script>
function closePopUp(data) {
 if (data.success) {
     //close popup
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ill give it a try! FYI, have you noticed putting inline javascript code in e.g. the OnSuccess does not work in Chrome when Unobtrusive is turned on? It can be fixed by using a function name.

Comment: I'll have to do more browser testing, but right now the above code works in Chrome 14, IE9 and FF7 using MVC3. I have seen a SO question stating that inline code was broken in MVC2 for the callback but was fixed in MVC3.

Comment: I updated the code to use a function name instead of inline code. I had to use the modal on more than one page and wanted it to stay DRY