# MVC a public action method was not found on controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(HelloWorldMvcApp.ProductData model, string[] imgToDelete)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
```

And Here's the View:

```
  @model HelloWorldMvcApp.ProductData model

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SharedLayout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divProductData", OnSuccess = "hideModal", Url = Html.Action("Save").ToHtmlString() }))
    {
        <div id="divProductData">
         <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.id)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.productDesc)
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            @foreach (string path in Model.picture.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="imgToDelete" value="@path">
                            <br />
                            <img src='~/Images/Product/@path' />
                        </td>
                    }
          </tr>


            </table>

        </div>
       }

  @section scripts{
      <script>
        function hideModal() {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        }
    </script>
  }
```

There is an exception thrown at  `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divProductData", OnSuccess = "hideModal", Url = Html.Action("Save").ToHtmlString() }))` :

> {"A public action method 'Save' was not found on controller
>   'HelloWorldMvcApp.ProductDataController'."}

Here's the fiddle for the code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/OLEq4o

How to fix this error?

I tried to use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm because this page is displayed inside the Bootstrap Modal and after some researches, I cannot call "hideModal" function if I use Html.BeginForm

[Close modal window containing ASP MVC Ajax form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431693/close-modal-window-containing-asp-mvc-ajax-form)

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If you wanting to generate a url, then its `@Url.Action("Save")`, not `@Html.Action("Save")` - `Html.Action()` calls a method and renders the partial view returned by the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... I figured out, first, I moved the action name outside the AjaxOptions, then I changed `[HttpPost]` attribute to  `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` in the controller, and added , `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the JSON result, here's the result:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kXnYlT

Comment: If you're truly doing a "Save", that is commonly a `POST` action. So feel free to leave the attribute of `[HttpPost]` on the controller and specify the method in the `AjaxOptions` -- `new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divProductData", OnSuccess = "hideModal" }`

Answer (score 0):

try specifying controller name.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divProductData", OnSuccess = "hideModal", Url = Html.Action("Save","controllerName").ToHtmlString() }))
```